# R fGARCH fitted Values

Tags: programming, garch

I am using the `fGARCh` package in R to analyze volatility of stock returns. More precisely I am using a `garch(1, 1)` fit. The code looks like this:

```
GARCH11<-garchFit(formula = ~garch(1, 1), data = Returns.zoo, trace = FALSE)
```

`Returns.zoo` is my time series.

Now I know the interpretation of GARCH@h.t and GARCH@sigma.t.
But what does GARCH@fitted tell me in relation to the time series and why is the value equal at all times?

I would be very relieved if someone could enlighten me. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

When fitting a volatility model, you have two series - one describing the actual data and one the data's volatility.

In your code, the volatility part is modelled by a GARCH(1,1) model, while the data is simply modelled with a constant term, which is included by default. Hence, your "fitted" model is just a constant term and `GARCH1@fitted` provides a constant value, which is equal to the mean coefficient `mu`.

If you additionally want to model the data series, you can add an ARMA model to your specification:

```
GARCH11<-garchFit(formula = ~arma(1,1)+garch(1, 1), data = Returns.zoo, trace = FALSE)
```

Then, the `@fitted` output will be time-varying, following an ARMA(1,1) process. As you said that you model stock returns, using an ARMA model probably isn't necessary, though.